# R: read.csv importing the letter i as NA

Tags: r, csv, na

Pretty simple question (I think). I'm trying to import a .csv file into R, from an experiment in which people respond by either pushing the "e" or the "i" key. In testing it, I responded only in with the "i" key, so the response variable in the data set is basically a list of "i"s (without the quotation marks). When I try and import the data into R:

```
noload=read.csv("~/Desktop/eprime check no load.csv", na.strings = "")
```

the response variable comes out all NAs. When I try it with all "e"s, or a mixture of "e" and "i", it works fine.

What is is about the letter i that makes R treat it as NA (n.b. it does this even without the `na.strings = ""` part)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Were the columns identified correctly? Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Strange... indeed `read.csv(text="i,i,i,i\ni,i,i,i\ni,i,i,i", header = FALSE)` all `NA`, but `read.csv(text="e,e,e,e\ne,e,e,e\ne,e,e,e", header = FALSE, na.strings = "")` works fine. Seems any column that is all `i` will be set to `NA`

Comment: Odd. As a workaround, you can use `readr::read_csv` or `data.table::fread`.

Comment: Even odder, `read.table` works just fine.

Comment: I think it's something with `colClasses`. If you set it to `'character'` or `'factor'`, it works. Maybe it's not sure if they're letters or imaginary numbers?

Comment: @lmo I think that's worthy of posting as solution. Just use `read.table(..., sep = ",")` works as expected

Comment: `read.table(..., sep = ",")` behaves just like `read.csv` for me.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I just saw that. Very strange.

Comment: @alistaire good point... it was only working if `header = FALSE` and there was indeed a header

Comment: `read.csv(text="i,i,i,i\ni,i,i,i\ni,i,i,i", header = FALSE)` does not have that behavior in R 3.3.0 RC on a Mac.

Comment: There's an issue with the underlying helper function: `type.convert('i')` returns `NA`.

Answer (score 6):

When you ask `R` to read in a table without specifying data types for the columns, it will try to "guess" the data types.  In this case, it guesses "complex" for the data type.  For example, if you had `datafile.csv` with contents

```
Var
i
i
i
```

and you do:

```
df = read.csv("datafile.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = "")
class(df$Var)
```

you'll get

```
[1] "complex"
```

`R` interprets the i as the [purely imaginary value](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/basic-data-types/complex).  To fix this simply specify the data types with `colClass`, like so:

```
df = read.csv("datafile.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = "", colClass = "factor")
```

or replace `factor` with whatever you want.  It's good practice usually to specify data types up front like this so you don't run into confusing errors later.

Comment: Indeed `dput(read.csv(text="V1,V2,V3,V4\ni,i,i,i\ni,i,i,i\ni,i,i,i"))` gives it away. But why isn't it displaying `0 + 1i`? Why is it assuming `i` is `NA`? I see `as.complex("i")` is `NA_complex_`, and `as.complex(i)` is also wrong (`300 + 0i)`)...

Comment: I filled this as a bug some time ago and this was fixed in the latest R release (v 3.3.0). See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2016/000602.html)